# Por que no hace nada la función system("cls")

Tags: c, vscode

En el siguiente código, la función system("cls") no surte ningún tipo de efecto, todo me compila a la perfección pero a la hora de ejecutar esta no hace nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>

void menuInicio();
void jugar();
void registrarse();
bool validezDeOpcion(char eleccion[], int opcionMayor, int opcionMenor);
void limpiarCadena(char cadena[]);

int main()
{
    menuInicio();
}

void menuInicio()
{
    char eleccion[20];
    printf("\n\n\t\tHola, introduce la opcion que desees ejecutar...\n\n\n\t");
    printf("a)  Registrarse\n\t");
    printf("b)  Jugar\n\t");
    printf("c)  Salir\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("Introduce tu eleccion aqui:  ");
    gets(eleccion);
    while (validezDeOpcion(eleccion, 99, 97) == false)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\tHola, introduce la opcion que desees ejecutar...\n\n\n\t");
        printf("a)  Registrarse\n\t");
        printf("b)  Jugar\n\t");
        printf("c)  Salir\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        printf("Has seleccionado una opcion invalida, intentalo de nuevo:  ");
        limpiarCadena(eleccion);
        gets(eleccion);
    }
}
void jugar();
void registrarse();

bool validezDeOpcion(char eleccion[], int opcionMayor, int opcionMenor)

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(eleccion); i++)
    {
        if (eleccion[1] > 0 || eleccion[0] == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (eleccion[i] < opcionMenor || eleccion[i] > opcionMayor)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
void limpiarCadena(char cadena[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < strlen(cadena); i++)
    {
        cadena[i] = 0; 
    }
}
```

Repito, todo me compila perfectamente únicamente que la función no hace nada. Por otro lado, uso [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode). Aunque se que las funciones que hacen uso de comandos propios del cmd no son efectivas (o al menos eso es lo que he leído), no encuentro nada mas útil que la del `system("cls")`. Lo raro es que he probado en otros compiladores ([codeblocks](/questions/tagged/codeblocks) específicamente) y todo va como se espera. Si no es mucha molestia, y si no se llega a ningún consenso, pido sugerencias de que otra función puedo utilizar para borrar pantalla que no sean muchos saltos de linea, este tipo de función mueve el cursor no borra la pantalla lo que genera que este quede en la parte inferior de la pantalla y eso es poco estético.

Comment: En Linux `system.("clear")` - el equivalente a `cls` -  funciona correctamente.

Comment: Volvi a intentarlo en Code::blocks y tampoco funciona, la solución fue buscar un código que hiciera lo mismo. SIn embargo aun tengo la duda...

Comment: Para hacer aplicaciones estéticas de consola deberías acudir a librerías de terceros como ncurses. Estas librerías hablan con la API del Sistema Operativo y facilitan la creación de entornos de consola más o menos bonitos. En cualquier caso yo no perdería mucho el tiempo en este tema si no es imprescindible. Las interfaces de usuario en entornos de consola no tienen mucho uso hoy en día salvo en aplicaciones muy muy específicas

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que la función system("cls"); pertenece a la librería stdlib.h. Has probado con ella?